# How to trim the end of horizontal lines in a table with vertical lines?

Tags: tables, booktabs

How to obtain something like this ?

[image]

The only way that I have found for trimming horizontal lines in a table is using booktabs.
The problem with booktabs is that it doesn't manage vertical lines well.

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\begin{tabular}{!{\color{gray}\vline}ll!{\color{gray}\vline}}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \cmidrule(rl){1-2}
  e & f
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But what I get the following output, which is not what I am looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\multispan{2}{\color{red}\vline\hspace*{.5em}\leaders \hrule height\arrayrulewidth\hskip\fill\hspace*{.5em}\vline}\\
  e & f
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why if I put your code in a \newcommand with options like this: `\newcommand{\htrimmedline}[1][2]{\multispan{#1}{\color{gray!40}\hspace*{.2em}\vline\hspace{.2em}\leaders \hrule height\arrayrulewidth\hskip\fill\hspace*{.2em}\vline\hspace{.2em}}\\}` when I compile I get the error `Misplaced omit`, while if I put it in a newcommand without optional argument like this: `\newcommand{\htrimmedline}[1]{\multispan{#1}{\color{gray!40}\hspace*{.2em}\vline\hspace{.2em}\leaders \hrule height\arrayrulewidth\hskip\fill\hspace*{.2em}\vline\hspace{.2em}}\\}`, it works?

Comment: @Robbo `\multicolumn`/`\multispan` and friends have to _expand_ to a sequence of tokens starting with `\omit` as TeX uses a special pre-scan to see if it should or should not start a normal table cell.  You can have nothing before `\omit` not even `\relax` (which does nothing).  The machinery used for testing if there is an optional argument does not work purely by expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `scalerel`'s `\stretchleftright` macro:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\stretchleftright{\color{gray}|}{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \cmidrule(rl){1-2}
  e & f
\end{tabular}%
}{\color{gray}|}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly the expected output because, in that environment, the vertical rules are never broken.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|ll|}[rules/color=gray]
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \cmidrule(rl){1-2}
  e & f
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

I will give an alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

Note that you need to put trim option `lr` inside the square brackets.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{|[gray]ll|[gray]} 
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \cmidrule[gray,lr]{1-2}
  e & f
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]